# Python XML Element AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, lxml, attributeerror, nonetype, xml.etree

I am trying to parse the following xml file.

```
<xml version="1">
    <nodes>
    1      -2.50000000E+01       0.00000000E+00       5.00000000E+00
    </nodes>
</xml>
```

I want to retrieve the values within the element `nodes` in that file. I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xtree = ET.parse("SafePGInput_t.dat")
xroot = xtree.getroot()

for node in xroot:
    s_nodes = node.find('nodes')
    print(s_nodes.text)
```

What is returned is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. I thought it would return a string. Just printing `s_nodes` returns `None`. How do I get the text of the four values in the element `nodes`? I want to load these values into pandas if possible, since I need to calculate a new row. The actual `nodes` element contains a large amount of rows with values that exceeds `pd.read_xml`s limit when using the parser 'lxml'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Ali

Comment: The real error here is your node.find.  the attribute error is a red herring bc you didn't check the node was actually found.  Prepare a mwe document and play with the xml parser until you figure out how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the tag of the current node use:

```
node.tag
```

To get the content, if the node is the one you want, use

```
node.text
```

In your case, maybe you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xtree = ET.parse("trash/d.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
for node in xroot:
    if node.tag == "nodes":
        print(node.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. What you suggested actually works for the given example. But what if I have multiple elements in the document? How can I adress just 'nodes' in that case?

Comment: @Ali Ah I see, I you want to check the current node tag, use `node.tag`,  it will output the current tag name of the node. I have edited my answer !

Comment: Thanks alot. I will keep on playing with your info. It helped alot.

Comment: Don't forget to close the topic and label the post that gave you the solution :)